# Getting JSON/JSONP/GeoJSON from GetFeature WFS request to ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, geojson, wfs, getfeature

I'm trying to perform a GetFeature request to an ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Server WFS service and would like to get response in GeoJSON format.

If I look at the GetCapabilities from the service the only output format available is:

```
<wfs:OutputFormats>
   <wfs:Format>text/xml; subType=gml/3.1.1/profiles/gmlsf/1.0.0/0</wfs:Format>
</wfs:OutputFormats>
```

Is it possible to have JSON, JSONP, or GeoJSON?

How to configure ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Server to do that?

Comment: it seems it's 10.21

Comment: You have solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from the question whether you are asking about the possibility of editing an ArcGIS service so that you can provide JSON, JSONP, or GeoJSON as part of a WFS service that you own, or are asking from the point of a user wishing to consume a WFS service.

**Looking at it from the a user perspective:**

In any OGC Web service, be it WMS, WFS, WCS etc, you can only request formats that are available (advertised) in a service through its GetCapabilities request response.  So in the above example, if only GML 3.1.1 is advertised, you can only make request for that format.

It should be noted that just because a piece of software might be capable of delivering a format, if the service provider decides to block that format they may choose to do so.